# Horizontal Date Slider using Coverflow design

Tags: android, coverflow

Before asking my question I want to post here two snapshots for better understanding.

1. What I have done so far.[image]
2. What I am trying to implement.[image]

I am using [this](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow) coverflow Api for achieving this functionality because Android Gallery is deprecated.

Now the problem is I am not getting View of the selected Item when coverflow scrolling is finished so I can Highlight it currently coverflow returns me position of the Item for example with following code.

```
    mCoverFlow.setOnScrollPositionListener(new FeatureCoverFlow.OnScrollPositionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolledToPosition(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolling() {
            mTitle.setText("");
        }
    });
```

And when I click on a item then I can change the border and code is here.

```
    mCoverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(new    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(CoverFlowActivity.this,
                getResources().getString(mData.get(position).titleResId),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        view.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

with above code I can highlight the Item as below.[image]

Please suggest me if it is possible to achieve this functionality using this coverflow Api.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys I have achieved this functionality.[image]

By modifying cover flow.